# Should i put my condition in the template or render a different template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm learning node js and using pug-template engine to create a simple login/admin page for hotel bookings.

When a user is logged in the index page should be different from a not logged in user.

Should i do a condition in my template or a condition in my home route to render a index_logged or index_not_logged?

Currently doing

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("index", {
        title: "Willkommen",
        users: users
      });
    }
  });
});
```

and in my index.pug

```
extends layout


block content
  if user
    h1 #{title}
    ul.list-group
      each user, i in users
        li.list-group-item
          a(href="/users/"+user._id)= user.name
  else
    .jumbotron
      h1 #{title}
      a(href="/users/login").btn.btn-primary Anmelden
```

I'm using a global user variable at the moment.

Comment: So its having two pages in one template vs two pages and each in a separate template? You should use one file per page and route them in your route controller.

Comment: Currently rendering an index.pug from my app.use('/' and doing in index.pug something like if user, render this, else render this.

Not sure if there is a right way to do so, though.

Edited the question to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your public `/` is very different from the logged in `/`, then render two separate pug views, example:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.render("public_index");
    } else {
      res.render("index", {
        title: "Willkommen",
        users: users
      });
    }
  });
});
```

But if the two pages are very similar with a few certain parts different, then render the same view but use `if user` (theoretically you can have this in as many places as you like in the view file) to display the relevant content accordingly, like what you have in the index.pug in your question. Your app logic should be:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    let Users = undefined;
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      Users = users
    }
    res.render("index", { title: "Wilkommen", users: Users });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i will look into it